# Should i use a hash or a new class for achievements in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm practicing ruby on rails and I'm trying to add achievements to users. I was wondering if anyone could explain the benefits/detriments to using a hash over a new class.

For example, should my object have a "has_many" relationship with an "achievement" object, or should there be a "achievement" hash and why? I'm mostly concerned with database speed implications.

Comment: Your question uses different verbiage but it is essentially answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270251/why-in-the-world-would-i-have-many-relationships. Serializing a `Hash` and embedding a model are functionally the same in the context of the question you are trying to answer.

Comment: What about if i'm trying to find a user with several achievements? Would the relationship itself slow it down?

Comment: @Mike: No, using `serialize` is almost always a mistake and is nowhere near to being functionally equivalent to using a relationship and a separate table. Attempting to look inside a serialized `Hash` in a database query is madness, JOINing to a separate table is quick, clean, and easy. Using PostgreSQL and its `jsonb` column type gets around most of the `serialize` problems but even then a separate table is usually a better choice.

Comment: What makes you think using a separate table has speed problems?

Comment: I assumed it would be slower if I added more tables. If for example I needed to look up everyone that had achievements A and B, wouldn't I need to search through multiple relationships and tables rather than search the one?

Comment: @muistooshort I think there is a misunderstanding. I was saying that using `serialize` on a `Hash` would be the same as "embedding data in field in a parent table" (from the other question). I did not mean to suggest that serializing data was the same as using two separate tables and creating a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should my object have a `has_many` relationship with an "achievement" object, or should there be a "achievement" hash and why?

I'd most certainly recommend a `has_many` relationship based on database backends - it gives you the ability to build the associative data as you require (instead of messing around with custom methods).

You must also realize that *ActiveRecord will build a hash for you*, right?

The only difference is that ActiveRecord will populate the hash with data from your db, whilst I believe you'll be talking about a hash of static data (which I've not massive experience with).

--

Since this question doesn't have many answers, this is how I'd do it:

```
#app/models/achievement.rb
class Achievement < ActiveRecord::Base
    ## you could attach this to MongoDB or some other file-based storage system 
   has_many :awards
   has_many :users, through : :awards
end

#app/models/award.rb
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :achievement
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :awards
   has_many :achievements, through: :award
end
```

This is a standard `has_many :through` relationship. I imagine you already know about it, so I'll not bore you with details; however, you have to remember that this type of setup is a standard in Rails -- it will give you the functionality you want without any of the customization your ideas will probably require.

It will give you the ability to call the following:

```
@awards = Award.joins(:achievements).where(user_id: @current_user.id)
```

This will take one DB call to bring back all the *achievements* for a single user, all related.

The data will be encapsulated in *classes* -- and will basically be a series of hashes, populated from the db.

The `Achievement` model could easily be converted to use static data.